# make messages dissappear in a time

Tags: django, django-views

Hello Stackoverflow community.

Django stuff

Does anyone know how to make automatically disappear  in a time (lets say in five seconds) messages provided by SuccessMessageMixin or by messages.add_message construction, without clicking on the [x] button on the each individual message?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this using javascript

in alert template

```
{% if messages %}
<ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
    <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

in javascript

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('.messages').fadeOut('fast');
}, 30000); // <-- time in milliseconds
```

hope it helps